# Rails - redirect to current url without one of the GET params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very simple problem in a Rails app that I can't find an elegant solution to.

I have a URL like: 
http://www.example.com/some-path/?foo=123&baz=456

And I want to process one of the params and do a redirect to:
http://www.example.com/some-path/?baz=456

I want this to work generally for any URL with param "foo", so I don't want to specify "baz" in the rewrite code.

What I want is something like:

```
redirect_to request.path, :params => request.query_parameters.except(:foo)
```

Except that doesn't quite work.  I know I can regex or parse the query string manually but I assume there's a better way.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Do you get an error? Do you get a URL you didn't expect?

Comment: The code above doesn't actually keep baz=456 in the redirect

Comment: For reference, this code does exactly what I want (apologize for formatting):

`query_string = request.query_parameters.except(:foo).map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('&')`

`redirect_to query_string ? "#{request.path}?#{query_string}" : request.path`

Comment: The code in your comment has multiple problems. You're not escaping those querystring params when you reconstruct the url. If any of them contain = or & or other special characters that should be encoded, you'll end up with a very broken redirected url. Also, this code will not properly deal with the automatic hash and array-ification of query parameters like `x[a]=1&x[b]=2` that request.query_parameters gives you.  These are two reasons why it is generally a bad idea to write your own querystring manipulation code, especially in a complex framework like rails.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The best way which I have found so far is to use:

```
url_for(params.except(:obsolete_param_name))
```

**UPDATE**

As [grosser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110333/grosser) mentioned this opens up a security hole in your application as an attacker can pass a host as a url param and redirect the user to a different website. In order to prevent this you can use [rap1ds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432787/rap1ds)'s suggestion and specify that only the path has to be used.

You can use a helper function like this one for this purpose:

```
def secure_path_for(params, *excluded_params)
  url_for(params.except(*excluded_params).merge(only_path: true))
end
```

Comment: This is a security hole, it will people redirect to a given host ?host=attacker.com -> attacker.com

Comment: You are right! So maybe another solution would be to wrap it in another method, which will make sure that keys like 'host' and etc. won't be modified (something similar to what strong parameters does to prevent mass assignments).

Comment: `url_for` has an option `only_path`, so if you don't need absolute URL, you can do `url_for(params.except(:obsolete_param_name).merge(only_path: true)` This should not expose any security issues, or does it? At least I can not come up with any.

Comment: I had to go to the current route with one parameter modified, I used: `url_for(params.merge({my_param: new_value}))`

Comment: what about `url_for(params.except(:obsolete_param_name, :host))` ?

Answer (score 8):

What about just deleting params[:foo] before you pass it along.  Maybe something like:

```
params.delete[:foo]
redirect_to request.path, :params => params
```

It's not really elegant, but it only adds one line. Params by the way is a helper method that get's the url's current parameters

Comment: Assuming the existing controller for /some-path/ can handle both forms  of expected URL (e.g. `if params[:foo]...`) then this is a perfectly appropriate solution.  You could create a named route that matches the  foo-less path, but that would make things less obvious, IMHO.

Comment: This is basically equivalent to what I did above (doesn't work), except params also pulls in params from the route, so you would possibly get extra stuff in the URL you didn't want.

Comment: yes, that's true. This assumes that the only goal is to remove the parameter :foo going into the redirect.

Answer (score 6):

In rails 5 you will get **non-sanitized request parameters** error if you attempt to do this `url_for(params.except(:param))`

So I found this way to do this:

```
request_url = request.url # eg. http://qwe.com/path?param1=1&param2=2

query_hash = Rack::Utils.parse_query(URI.parse(request_url).query).except('param1')
url = query_hash.empty? ? request.path : "#{request.path}?#{query_hash.to_query}"

puts url #=> /path?my_param2=2

redirect_to url
```

Answer (score 2):

```
uri = URI.parse(request.url)
new_query = uri.query.split("&").reject{|pair|
  k,v = pair.split("=")
  k =~ /^foo\[?/ # reject params named "foo" or "foo[anything"
}.join("&")
# if the new querystring is empty, assign nil instead of "" so we don't
# end up with a solitary question mark at the end of the url.
uri.query = (new_query.empty? ? nil : new_query)
redirect_to uri.to_s
```

I came to the above solution after running into some non-obvious problems with trying to do things the "Rails way," if there is such a way, to solve this issue. For instance:

- Rails parameter parsing will automagically instantiate arrays and hashes for query params that use the special square bracket syntax: `?x[a]=1&y[]=2` becomes `{"x"=>{"a"=>"1"}, "y"=>["2"]}` and so on, so code that uses the provided querystring and param routines are tricky to deal with in this regard. And filtering params by raw string value can be difficult as a result. Even the non-rails/rack CGI module will give you arrays instead of strings for the param values.
- The rails `params` hash includes both GET, POST, and routing parameters, such as `:action` and `:controller` so you couldn't just re-use that to reconstruct a querystring anyway.
- As such, the URL helpers like url_for are not much help.

Given these issues I found I was not able to use provided framework functionality to get a pure and unmolested querystring, reproduced as-is from the current request, that simply and only removes one parameter. The code above seems to work well, however.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes to this later, this is what worked for me

```
link_to request.params.except(:param)
```