# Ruby on Rails: 301 redirect variable underscore URLs to hypen URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461178/rails-redirect-to-current-url-without-one-of-the-get-params) is similar but not the same.

Assume routes like `/test/foo_bar` and `/test/foo_bar/8`.

`routes.rb` has routes like:

```
  get "/test/:id1/:id2", to: "test#super"
  get "/test/:id1", to: "test#duper"
```

If the goal is to 301 redirect underscore URLs to hyphen versions (e.g., `/test/foo_bar` -> `/test/foo-bar`), is there a Rails way to do this programmatically? Or is it necessary to manually create 301 routes for the old underscore routes?

This is for Rails 6.x.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not a redirect to me. As "foo_bar" is just a param (id1). Params are usually user submitted or assigned by the app when a record is created. If you think some params are no longer valid the way they used to be (with an underscore) then you may batch change them in database and waarn the user if they are user submitted.

Comment: alternatively, in the controller method (either duper or super) just modify the param before it is tested against anything in database. As redirecting "/test/foo_bar" to "/test/foo-bar" is still pinging the same route: test controller and duper method.

Comment: ........ If I'm understanding correctly, you don't need to do redirects. You can apply it directly in your routes file. i.e. `get "/test/foo_bar", to: "test#foobar"; get "/test/foo-bar", to: "test#foobar" - you will notice that both routes point to the same controller action. if your needs become more complex, then i'm fairly confident you can use various constraints (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) to parse your routes and direct to to the correct route. Maxence has a solution too if the foo-bar or foo_bar actually means something in your database.

Comment: @Maxence thanks for the help, but unfortunately these are not maintained in the database, and we can't alert the user. can we programmatically remap underscore routes to hyphen routes, or do we need to manually redirect reach route?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon yes, one solution is to manually define the routes, but we hope to avoid this if possible as there are a few. is it possible to programmatically redirect these underscore routes to their hypen versions?

Comment: @Crashalot solved?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this (untested):

```
 get '/test/:id1', to: redirect { |path_params, req| "/test/#{path_params[:id1].dasherize}" }
 get '/test/:id1/:id2', to: redirect { |path_params, req| "/test/#{path_params[:id1].dasherize}/#{path_params[:id2]}" }
```

I don't like this approach: it feels hacky....but it may work for you.